Error: VM option 'UseG1GC' is experimental and must be enabled via -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions. Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine
I install JAVA 8 from Oracle's offcial website on my new mac.
I want to run unit tests for my scala project on my local.
I am able to build the project with mvn clean install -DskipTests successfully.
However when running mvn test I am getting below error.
Error: VM option 'UseG1GC' is experimental and must be enabled via -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Any help to fix this will be greatly appreciated.
TIA
I tried enabling the flag using belwo command but it did not fixed the issue.
java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep UnlockExperimentalVMOptions ```

